# How can I know if my WiFi network card supports packets injection?

Tags: wireless-networking, packet-injection

The card is Intel Centrino Advanced N-6200.
[ http://www.intel.com/network/connectivity/products/wireless/adapters/6200-6300/ ]

I need it to inject packets, so I run search in google to check it it's supports packet injection, but couldn't find any relevant result.
I'm new with all this packet-injections using, so can someone please help me with this research?  I just need to know if this card (which I already purchased) will support this feature.

OS to be in used: Linux ubuntu.

Many thanks

Comment: This should help you out.
http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/beginners-forum/2236-intel-6200-adapter-firmware-update.html

Answer (score 2):

Is it already installed on the linux system?  If so then running:

```
aireplay-ng -9 [interface name]
```

will run an injection test.  Normally I believe this can later be fiddled, if it fails, by using different drivers though stability may take a hit.  aireplay is part of the aircrack suite available in synaptics package manager or via apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

The [aircrack-ng website](http://aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=tutorial) has a tutorial that covers how to test injection as well as all other steps needed.